# integrating both side with different function on each side

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation in a solution.
$\theta$ is a function of $t$
$$\ddot\theta=\sin{\theta}$$
and integrate both side to get
$$\dot\theta = t\sin{\theta}+C$$
I am not very sure about what happened on the righthand side or is it even correct. I have a vague feeling that it looks like (reverse)chain rule, but I can't write it down to convince myself. Can someone explain it a bit?
If it's not correct, I get this, is it right? 
$$-\frac{1}{\dot\theta}\cos\theta$$

Comment: If $\theta = t^2$ then your equation is $2=\sin t^2$. Certainly that does not become $2t=t\sin t^2 +C$

Comment: This is only a part of a question, in the question I have initial value for C, I don't think I have to worry what function C is? Or do I?

Comment: your identity is just wrong. You cannot integrate $\sin\theta$ without knowing what function is $\theta$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your integration is incorrect. This is a differential equation, and its solution does not yield to that exact procedure. You can do this:
\begin{align*}
\ddot{\theta}&=\sin(\theta) \\
\ddot{\theta}\dot{\theta}&=\sin(\theta)\,\dot{\theta} \qquad\text{multiply by }\dot{\theta}\\
\int\dot{\theta}\,\ddot{\theta}\,dt&=\int\sin(\theta)\,\dot{\theta}\,dt \\
\frac{\dot{\theta}^2}{2}&=-\cos(\theta)+C \qquad u \text{ substitution on both sides}
\end{align*}
That's one integration. The second integration can be written in terms of elliptic integrals:
\begin{align*}
\dot{\theta}^2&=C-2\cos(\theta) \qquad\text{absorb }2\text{ into constant.} \\
\frac{d\theta}{dt}&=\sqrt{C-2\cos(\theta)} \\
\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{C-2\cos(\theta)}}&=dt \\
\int\frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{C-2\cos(\theta)}}&=\int dt=t_{f}-t_{i}. \\
\end{align*}
And that's about as far as you can go symbolically.

Comment: I think this is not totally right, I mean, when you take square roots to both sides you can take also a negative value in the RHS, thus it would be more correct to state $\pm\sqrt{C-2\cos\theta}$ instead of just the square root. Also we can't just pass the square root to the other side and integrate if it is zero at some value of $t$, that is, it must be the case that $C-2\cos\theta\neq 0$ for some open interval. Besides that it seems all right.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Adrian Keister's answer, the solution of
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\sqrt{C-2\cos(\theta)}$$ is given by
$$\theta=2 \text{am}\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{C-2} \left(t+c_1\right)|-\frac{4}{C-2}\right)$$ where appears [the amplitude for Jacobi elliptic functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html).